# How to operate and reassign multiple variables

Tags: ruby

I'm taking a number of variables in ruby and dividing them by some other constant.

I'm wondering if there's a DRY-er way to write something like the below:

```
ela_articles /= ela_active_students.to_f
ela_days /= ela_active_students.to_f
ela_growth /= ela_active_students.to_f
ela_at_above_now /= ela_active_students.to_f
ela_at_above_before /= ela_active_students.to_f
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". And, if you supplied a working example, [codereview.se] would be a good place to consider asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to apply the same method to multiple variables at the same time you can do the following:

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 5

a, b = [a,b].map { |n| n.fdiv c }

a #=> 2.0
b #=> 4.0
```

Here we're using parallel assignment to redefine the variables `a` and `b`. For the division we've used [Fixnum#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-fdiv) which divides `n` by `c` and returns a float. You can of course use `n/c.to_f` instead.